# redirect any link on any subdomain-url to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I registered a expired domain to forward all incoming links to another domain. The problem is: many inlinks are placed on subdomains, for example: axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu/axa-art/0eee9cec-58cb-45b2-a4e2-b5f73920068e_091216_axa+art_classic+car+study_de_rz.pdf

I am looking for a 301 redirect rule in htaccess that forward any url (no matter on main domain or subdomain) to "new-url.tld"

```
axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu
axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu/slug
any-subdomain.contento-v41.eu
any-subdomain.contento-v41.eu/slug
```

all of this example above should
forward to this exact URL: new-domain.tld

**Question 1:**
Is it possible to create a "general" rule and place it into htaccess of the main directory?

**Question 2:**
Or do i have to write a specific rule for each subdomain?

**Question 3:**
Do I have to create a sub-directory and create a separate htaccess in every sub-directory for each subdomain I want to add redirection-rules?

Help or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: This is not clear, please do add your htaccess file along with samples of URLs for better understanding of your question thank you.

Comment: I am not sure how my htaccess file can help you because I don't know what rule to add. But I have attached it. this rule does forward any URL form the main domain to the new domain. But for the "subdomain-dilemma" I don't have a specific rule yet.

Comment: # Permanent URL redirect- by netgrade 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !https://www.marco-mahling.de/$ 
RewriteRule $ https://www.marco-mahling.de/ [R=302,L]

Comment: Why I am asking to add htaccess file in your question because it's encouraged on SO for original posters to add their efforts. You could edit your question and add it . Also see this link how you could post a Good question with samples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778994/htaccess-redirect-domain-lang-to-subdomain-for-each-language which will help us to understand your question better, cheers.

Comment: Will do. Give me a moment. And see how I can explain and edit my question a bit easier.

Comment: "I am not sure how my htaccess file can help you" - Apart from seeing what you have already tried to solve the immediate problem, Apache directives work _together_, not necessarily in isolation, so you can end up with conflicts if they are put in the wrong place. You should also _edit_ your question to include additional code. Important formatting can be lost in comments.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't just a `.htaccess` question. In order for your server to receive requests to `<any-subdomain>.example.com` the necessary DNS and server config directives need to be in place. If the request doesn't reach your server then you can't implement a redirect in `.htaccess`.

So, I suspect that these subdomains are not even resolving?

You either need to create the necessary DNS `A` records and `ServerAlias` directives one by one for each hostname (ie. subdomain) or create a "wildcard" DNS `A` record (and `ServerAlias *.example.com` directive in the vHost). But then you still have an issue with these hostnames being covered by an SSL cert if you need to redirect from HTTPS.

You can then create the necessary redirect in `.htaccess`. Although, since you need access to the server config (or a using a control panel that does this for you) to implement the directives above, you should also implement this redirect in the server config also.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing directives (or in your vHost):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new\.example$
RewriteRule ^ https://new.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above states... for any request that is not for `new.example` then 301 redirect to `https://new.example/<same-url>`.

However, if you have access to the server config and this other domain is configured in its own vHost container then the redirect can be simplified:

```
Redirect 301 / https://new.example/
```

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> this rule does forward any URL form the main domain to the new domain.
>
> ```
> # Permanent URL redirect- by netgrade
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !https://www.marco-mahling.de/$
> RewriteRule $ https://www.marco-mahling.de/ [R=302,L]
> ```

The rule I posted above should probably replace your existing rule entirely.

Yes, your rule does redirect every URL to the *root* of the new domain, but it is arguably incorrect. The `RewriteCond` directive is superflous and isn't actually doing anything. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path, it *never* contains the scheme + hostname. So, the `RewriteCond` directive you've posted will *always* be successful.

If that is the rule you currently have then it would already redirect *everything*. In which case your problem would seem to the necessary DNS and server config directives as mentioned above.

From your directives, I assume that the other domain actually points to a different server (or different vHost on the same server). Otherwise, this would have resulted in a redirect-loop. In which case, you only need the much simpler `Redirect` directive that I posted above.

---

> **UPDATE#2:** That works fine BUT the incoming links are still not forwarded cuz of a "%" in the `url`: `https://axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu/axa-art%2F0eee9cec-58cb-45b2-a4e2-b5f73920068e_091216_axa+art_classic+car+study_de_rz.pdf`

It's actually because of the `%2F` - an encoded slash (`/`) in the URL-path. By default, Apache will reject such URLs with a 404 (for security reasons).

To allow encoded slashes in the URL you would need to set `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in the server config (or vHost container). You cannot set this in `.htaccess`. (The server generated 404 occurs before `.htaccess` is even processed.)

However, I would express caution about enabling this feature. (Is there a specific requirement here? Are you recreating these documents on the new server?)

If this request was intended to map directly to a PDF file on disk then this actually looks like an incorrectly URL encoded request, since a slash `/` is not a permitted filename character on either Windows or Linux.

If you enable `AllowEncodedSlashes` then the above `RewriteRule` will redirect the request to `/axa-art/0eee9cec....pdf` - note the %-decoded `/` in the resulting URL. You would need to take additional steps to maintain the URL-encoding (if that was required), but as I say, that looks like a mistake to begin with.

Comment: Hello MrWhite,
thanks for your help. I tried several things. I did not manage it with your .htaccess rule

What I did instead: I created the subdomain axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu
Here I added another .htaccess file with the same rules like described above.
That works fine BUT the incoming links are still not forwarded cuz of a "%" in the url: https://axa-art.cdn.contento-v41.eu/axa-art%2F0eee9cec-58cb-45b2-a4e2-b5f73920068e_091216_axa+art_classic+car+study_de_rz.pdf

Comment: Do you have an idea what I can do to solve this problem? Maybe when I add another rule, that forward 404 to "new-domain.tld" would that work?

Comment: "I created the subdomain" - Yes, that's what I stated in the first part of my answer. Unless you have other requirements for these subdomains then they should all point to the same location - you should not have to create "another" `.htaccess` file. You only need one file and one rule - as stated above. The 404 is caused by an encoded slash `%2F` in the URL-path. However, this would need access to the main server config to resolve. I've updated my answer. What is the purpose of redirecting these "old" URLs?